# nativescript <GridLayout> - How can i define 6 rows or more in a simple way?

Tags: nativescript, grid-layout, nativescript-vue

I can't find a simple solution for defining 6 rows (or more) and 1 column in a **GridLayout**.
For 6 rows now i have to say :

```
   <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto" columns="*">
```

This is the correct output, but i want to extend my rows optional.

[image]

Is there a shorter way to define this, or for any more desired rows?
The documentation is very confusing for this problem (for me).
thx

```
<FlexboxLayout class="page">
          <StackLayout class="form">
            <!--   <Label class="header" text="new contact"></Label> -->

            <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto" columns="*">
              <StackLayout row="0" class="input-field">
                <TextField
                  class="input"
                  hint="Name"
                  keyboardType="email"
                  autocorrect="false"
                  autocapitalizationType="none"
                  returnKeyType="next"
                ></TextField>
                <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>

              <StackLayout row="1" class="input-field">
                <TextField class="input" ref="FirstName" hint="FirstName" secure="false"></TextField>
                <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
              </StackLayout> ...
```

Comment: Use a StackLayout inside GridLayout on first column, so you can add as many items you want and still keep the second column fixed for anything you like.

Comment: i posted the code in my first post. But it is not working this way.

Comment: Please share the complete layout or possibly a Playground sample so it's easy to check the issue.

Comment: i will try to make a playground.

Comment: I guess there is no shorter syntax for defining rows and columns. You could [add them programmatically](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/blob/master/app/ns-ui-widgets-category/layouts/grid-layout/grid-layout-page.js), but since your `GridLayout` is wrapped in a `StackLayout` why not work inside it?